How to correctly count "true" solutions to $x^n = 1 \bmod m$?
I got sidetracked (again) during the investigation of one of my other questions and started wondering how the cycles in the following picture came to be:

What you see here is the graph generated by the edge set $(k,k^2 \bmod m)$ for $k = 0,\ldots,m-1$ (here $m = 43$) or more simply the behaviour of iterating the function $f\colon \mathbb{Z}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m,x \mapsto x^2$. Note that $m$ is not necessarily prime. Immediately, some questions come to mind:

When does a cycle of a certain length exist? (Fairly easy to answer: A true cycle of length $k$ exists iff $(2^{k}-1)\mid \phi(m)$ but not $(2^{l}-1) \mid \phi(m)$ for any $l < k$ where $\phi$ is the Euler Phi function.)
How many nodes in total are part of a cycle? (A bit harder to answer: It is given by a multiplicative function $g$ that is defined on prime powers by $g(p^k) = \text{Od}(p-1) \cdot p^{k-1} + 1$ for $p \neq 2$ and $g(2^k) = 2$ for $p = 2$, where $\text{Od}$ is the odd part function that strips the number of its powers of $2$.)
How many cycles of a given length are there for a given number $m$? How many of those are true cycles of a given length (i.e. not cycles of order a divisor of $m$)?

This question concerns the third part. Let's limit the scope to repeated squaring since the method is straightforwardly generalizable to other numbers. For a start, we are looking for solutions of the equation $x^{2^{k}} = x \pmod m$ or $x^{2^{k}-1} = 1 \pmod m$ for $x \neq 0$. Thankfully, as we can see in the answer to this question, there is a closed form for the number of solutions to $x^{2^{k}-1} = 1 \pmod m$, namely the multiplicative function $s_{2^{k}-1}$ defined on prime powers by
$$s_n(p^k) := \gcd(n,\phi(p^k))$$
for $p \neq 2$ and
$$s_n(2^k) := \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1 &: k < 2,
\\
\gcd(n,2) &: k = 2,
\\
\gcd(n,2)\gcd(n,2^{k-2}) &: k > 2
\end{array}\right.$$
for $p = 2$. This answers the first part (in the sense of "How many nodes part of a cycle of a given length?"). For the second part, I thought (for fixed cycle length $k$) of some kind of inclusion-exclusion of cycle lengths dividing $k$ and dividing the total number of "true" solutions by $k$, i.e.
$$c_{n,k}(m) := \frac{(-1)^{\Omega(k)}}{k}\sum\limits_{d\mid k}(-1)^{\Omega(d)}s_{2^d-1}(m)$$
where $\Omega(n)$ is the function counting the prime factors of $n$ with multiplicity. This formula clearly cannot be right though, since looking at the following picture for the edge set $(k,k^2 \bmod 103)$

we see that there are $2$ ($1$ if not counting $0$), $1$, $0$ and $6$ true cycles of length $1$, $2$, $4$ and $8$ respectively but
$$s_{2^1-1}(103) = 1$$
$$s_{2^2-1}(103) = 3$$
$$s_{2^4-1}(103) = 3$$
$$s_{2^8-1}(103) = 51$$
which yields $c_8(103) = \frac{50}{8}$ instead of $6$ (since there are some solutions mistaken as having cycle length $4$). My question is:

What is the correct way to define $c_{k}(m)$ so that it counts the amount of true $k$-cycles in the graph with edge set $(a,a^2 \bmod m)$ for $a = 0,\ldots,m-1$?


Wouldn't inclusion–exclusion use the Möbius function $\mu(d)$ instead of $(-1)^{\Omega(d)}$?

@GregMartin I don't have any former formal experience with number theory, so you could be right.

@GregMartin Damn it, I just noticed that this formula falls apart, because I did not pay attention to the solutions of $x(x^{n-1}-1) = 0 \mod m$ when $\mathbb{Z}_m$ can have zero divisors. I don't see how this approach is salvageable...

Suggestion: The Chinese remainder theorem implies that the number of roots of any polynomial modulo $m$ is the product of the number of roots of that polynomial modulo each prime power exactly dividing $m$. And modulo prime power $p^r$, either $x$ is a multiple of $p$ and then the only cycle is the fixed point $0\pmod{p^r}$, or else $x$ is relatively prime to $p^r$ and then $x^n\equiv x\pmod{p^r}$ is equivalent to $x^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^r}$.

Ah, so just adding 1 to each prime power definition of $s_n$ (except $s_n(1)$) should do the trick. I could swear I tried that yesterday and it didn't give me the right results, but now it does for some reason. I will report back if there are still problems with it. In the meantime, thanks!

@GregMartin I hope you are okay with that I posted an answer to my question in the meantime. If you have any problems with that please let me know.

There is a factorization method, the "Pollard-rho method", based on these cycles for a quadratic polynomial modulo the number you're trying to factor.

Thanks to @GregMartin I was able to correct my formula. I present to you the corrected formula
$$c_k(m) := \frac{1}{k}\sum\limits_{d|k} \mu\left(\frac{k}{d}\right) s_{2^{d}-1}(m)$$
where $s_n(m)$ is now defined on prime powers by
$$s_n(p^k) := \gcd(n,\phi(p^k))+1$$
for $p \neq 2$ and
$$s_n(2^k) := \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
2 &: k < 2,
\\
\gcd(n,2)+1 &: k = 2,
\\
\gcd(n,2)\gcd(n,2^{k-2})+1 &: k > 2
\end{array}\right.$$
for $p = 2$. How did we arrive at this corrected formula? Let's focus on the new definition of $s_n$ first. As Greg Martin noticed, the amount of solutions to
$$x^n \equiv x \mod m$$
is exactly equal to the product of the amount of solutions to
$$x^n \equiv x \mod p_i^{a_i}$$
for each prime power (where $m = p_1^{a_1} \cdots p_j^{a_j}$) thanks to the Chinese Remainder theorem. We have
$$x^n \equiv x \mod p_i^{a_i} \iff x(x^{n-1}-1) \equiv 0 \mod p_i^{a_i}$$
Now if $p_i \, | \, x_s$ for a solution $x_s$ to this polynomial, then we must have $x_s \equiv 0$ since the other factor cannot contribute any powers of $p_i$ (notice that $p_i \, | \, x_s^{n-1}$ so $p_i \nmid (x_s^{n-1}-1)$). This contributes one solution in total.
If $p_i \nmid x_s$ we get that $\gcd(x_s,p_i^{a_i}) = 1$ and by Bezout we know that we can find an inverse to $x_s$, reducing the problem to solutions of $x^{n-1}-1 = 0 \mod p_i^{a_i}$. This contributes $s_n(p_i^{a_i})$ many solutions (for the definition in the linked post), making a total of $s_n(p_i^{a_i})+1$ solutions.
To arrive at the inclusion-exclusion formula, we start by noticing that
$$s_{2^{k}-1}(m) = \sum\limits_{d|k} d \cdot c_d(m)$$
by definition of the functions as given in the OP (the total number of nodes in cycles even including cycles with length dividing $k$ is the sum of all nodes in "true" cycles of length a divisor). This formula lends itself extremly well to Moebius inversion, and indeed by applying the inversion formula we get
$$k \cdot c_k(m) = \sum\limits_{d|k} \mu\left(\frac{k}{d}\right) s_{2^{d}-1}(m)$$
which directly yields the desired formula.
